# Указать точку входа в Xamarin

Tags: xamarin-studio

Как явно указать точку входа в Xamarin 6.1 в приложение? Искал долго, нашел только вот то, что на скрине, но толку от этого 0, ибо ни название класса, ни название файла не принимает, пишет, что не нашёл метод Main, хотя он там есть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вместе с названием класса, надо было вводить еще и название проекта, через точку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]